# Delete Datagrid row (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatable, datagrid

Main window of application has Data grid , which is populated from database. 
( bind Data grid  from data table).

Data grid has 3 column-

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header= Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="250"></DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Header= Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="250"></DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="*">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Button Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Width="90" Click="btnEdit_Click" />
             <Button Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete" Width="90" Click="btnDelete_Click" />
         </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

when the time of window loading, datagrid poulated with data table.

```
    DataTable o_DataTable = new DataTable();
    o_DataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
    o_DataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            o_DataTable.Rows.Add("1","A");
            o_DataTable.Rows.Add("2","B");

        this.grd.ItemsSource = o_DataTable.DefaultView;
```

Below code for Delete button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object item = grd.SelectedItem;
            string CourseName = (grd.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the course " + CourseName + "?");
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                grd.Items.RemoveAt(grd.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
```

when I click delete button exception has been thrown

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.
```

Please any one suggest any idea to overcome this error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you want to remove the items from grid you can try this method

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object item = grd.SelectedItem;
            string CourseName = (grd.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the course " + CourseName + "?");
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                var itemSource = grd.ItemsSource as DataView;

                itemSource.Delete(grd.SelectedIndex);

                grd.ItemsSource = itemSource;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
grd.Items.RemoveAt(grd.SelectedIndex);
```

You should be removing from the underlying source.

Try removing it from the datatable and it will disappear from the view. Taking a MVVM approach makes it easier as you never need to touch the UI.